# Precompiling standard library header files - C++

Tags: c++, header-files, precompiled-headers

In my project several STL headers are used in different files. I read that, putting all these headers into a single header and using that header in my files will allow compilers to precompile the header which may lead into faster compile time.

If I understood it correctly, I need to write like the following.

```
// stl.hpp
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
```

Now include `stl.hpp` in all the files that needs access to STL. Is this correct?

Few of my files will be using only functionality from `vector` header file. But if I follow the above method, it will include unnecessary headers. Will this make any problem? Is there any code generated if I include a header file and not used anything from that?

Any help would be great!

Comment: I'm highly skeptical about the claim that including all the header files in a single header file will lead to faster compile time.

Comment: `C++ Templates - The complete guide` says, it does. I am not sure though.

Comment: It is pretty easy to time the compilation, just give it a try to see if there is significant improvement.

Comment: `stl.hpp` is probably a misnomer. Whether `<string>` is part of the STL is at least debatable. (Note: The STL was a container/iterator/algorithm library, developed by Alexander Stepanov. It was incorporated into what was, until then, the draft C++ standard library, delaying the standardization of C++98 for about one year. While doing so, the language and the rest of the library was extended and the STL was changed, so that it all would fit together better. Among others, `std::basic_string` got a container interface, templates where extended, and the STL adopted to use the extended templates.)

Comment: @Charles Including the headers in a single header file isn't what speeds up the compilation; what speeds it up is that all of the pre-compiled headers are scanned and compiled once and never looked at again during subsequent builds (assuming they haven't changed in the interim).  This can provide significant speed-ups depending on the number and size of header files in your project.

Comment: Try, measure, share results.

Answer (score 2):

Basically every decent compiler uses [precompiled headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header). Already compiled headers will be **cached** and **only recompiled if they were changed**.

Using already compiled headers instead of recompiling them every time speeds up compilation time.

But whether you combine commonly used headers in a singe file or include them in each source file separately won't matter in terms of compilation speed.

Answer (score 0):

Before attempting to speed-up you build by using pre-compiled headers, it's worth benchmarking/timing your existing builds to see if the speed-up will be worth the effort.

If you only have a few dozen files with `#include <string>` you may see no improvement.  If you have 1000s of file, then it may be worth it.

See this article for more excellent info:  [www.cygnus-software.com](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/precompiledheaders.html)